# Add a line in middle of txtfile in cmd

Tags: cmd

here's a text file `txtfile.txt`

```
line1
line2
add after this line
line4
etc
etc
```

i want to create a batch file which can add a line after `add after this line` with the user entered info. keeping the `add after this line` intact.

example:

```
enter info: asdf
```

and the file becomes

```
line1
line2
add after this line
asdf
line4
etc
etc
```

i think that the basic process would be to loop through the file copying it and when i find the line, adding the line and then looping through the rest. i want to know how to do it.

Comment: oh and the add afterthisline may contain %, | etc like characters, which make it harder in batch

Comment: How does the addafterthisline information get supplied? OK- it ***may*** contain poison characters - but is it contained in a variable, or supplied from a `set/p` or from a file, or what?

Comment: it gets supplied from another batch file. but it will be same as a txtfile (i think)

Comment: forget the **may** make it, it **will**, then how do i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET /p info="enter info : "
:: read addafter line
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (poison1.txt) DO (
SET addafter=%%i
FOR /f "delims=" %%n IN (' findstr /n "^" txtfile.txt') DO (
SET line=%%n
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET line=!line:*:=!
ECHO(!line!
IF "!line!"=="!addafter!" ECHO(%info%
ENDLOCAL
)
)
)>newfile.txt

FC newfile.txt txtfile.txt

GOTO :eof
```

Where `poison1.txt` contains the one line

```
"A line !of! ] many < & >var*ied %poison ^ char;ac(ters) | like "," a\nd+so=on"
```

and txtfile.txt contains this line.

- Read the line from the `poison1.txt` file to `addafter`
- For each line in the add-to-me file

  - Number the line to catch empty lines
  - Remove the number and first colon (added by `FINDSTR`)
  - Output the line verbatim
  - if the line matches the target, output the extra line

done!

Comment: why do you call it boring??

Comment: Please use the search function or google to find much more answers to this. It isn't a really interresting issue.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's necessary to know a part of the answer to find good results. But, nevertheless, Peter Wright gave you a good solution :-)

Comment: what about if the info (multi line) is stored in a.txt and i want to copy it in said place, how can i change the program??

Comment: Simply change `ECHO(%info%` to `TYPE extra_lines.txt`

Comment: FYI, 10 years later this is the main answer you get from searching google for batch file how insert line in middle of text file