# add multiple lines in middle of txtfile

Tags: cmd

ok 
here a file `txt.txt`

```
line1
line2
add after this line
line4
etc
etc
```

and another file `addthis.txt`
which contains multiple lines

i want to add all those lines in addthis after `add after this line`

what i want to know is what all changes i have to make in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918066/add-a-line-in-middle-of-txtfile-in-cmd) to accomplish it??

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [add line after a line in cmd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997228/add-line-after-a-line-in-cmd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET /p info="enter info : "
:: read addafter line
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (poison1.txt) DO (
SET addafter=%%i
FOR /f "delims=" %%n IN (' findstr /n "^" txtfile.txt') DO (
SET line=%%n
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET line=!line:*:=!
ECHO(!line!
IF "!line!"=="!addafter!" TYPE your_multiline_addition.txt
ENDLOCAL
)
)
)>newfile.txt

FC newfile.txt txtfile.txt

GOTO :eof
```

Just need to `TYPE your_multiline_addition.txt` rather than `ECHO(%input%`

(and you can probably toss away your input, too)

OR

you could

```
TYPE "%info%"
```

if you want to enter the name of the file containing the extras

---

Test data and Results:

```
======== poison1.txt ===========
"A line !of! ] many < & >var*ied %poison ^ char;ac(ters) | like "," a\nd+so=on"
======== extra_lines.txt ===========
extra line one
extra line two
extra line three
======== txtfile.txt ===========
line one 
line two 
line three
A line !of! ] many < & >var*ied %poison ^ char;ac(ters) | like "," a\nd+so=on

line 5 was blank - this is line FIVE
"A line !of! ] many < & >var*ied %poison ^ char;ac(ters) | like "," a\nd+so=on"

line 8 was blank - this is line NINE
======== newfile.txt ===========
line one 
line two 
line three
A line !of! ] many < & >var*ied %poison ^ char;ac(ters) | like "," a\nd+so=on

line 5 was blank - this is line FIVE
"A line !of! ] many < & >var*ied %poison ^ char;ac(ters) | like "," a\nd+so=on"
extra line one
extra line two
extra line three

line 8 was blank - this is line NINE
```

Comment: ok, but i have a `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` way up in the same batch file, how do i disable it for `SET line=%%n` to work? i tried `setlocal disabledelayedexpansion` just before `SET line=%%n` but it said maximum setlocal recursion level reached

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Is the `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` (`SET` won't work) earlier than this entire routine? The `SET line=%%n` should be unaffected in any case - and your question was how to insert multiple lines rather than the one line you originally specified.

Comment: For each `SETLOCAL` you need a matching `ENDLOCAL` as is shown in the routine above - the `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` is matched by the `ENDLOCAL` 4 lines later. When ENDLOCAL is reached, the environment is restored to its state when the `SETLOCAL` was executed. It's possible to change the original environment by executing `ENDLOCAL&set var=%var%` to set `var` to the final value of `var` established in the `SETLOCAL..ENDLOCAL` bracket. BUT - reaching end-of-file is the same as reaching an ENDLOCAL and terminates the current-innermost SETLOCAL.

Comment: the type cmd doesnt work as expected. it only copies a blank line to the file

Comment: Doesn't for me. Copies the entire content of the file `TYPE`d

Comment: got it, my posion file had an extra space at the end, thats what caused it. thanks a lot for your time