# add line after a line in cmd

Tags: cmd

ok here a file txt.txt

```
line1
line2
add after this line  blah blah blah
line4
etc
etc
```

i want to add a lines after add after this line but i dont know what comes in the same line after `add after this line`

what i want to know is what all changes i have to make in [this] code

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET /p info="enter info : "
:: read addafter line
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (poison1.txt) DO (
SET addafter=%%i
FOR /f "delims=" %%n IN (' findstr /n "^" txtfile.txt') DO (
SET line=%%n
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET line=!line:*:=!
ECHO(!line!
IF "!line!"=="!addafter!" TYPE your_multiline_addition.txt
ENDLOCAL
)
)
)>newfile.txt

FC newfile.txt txtfile.txt

GOTO :eof
```

any help is much appreciated.

dont know how to use wild cards in string manipulation

Comment: Why do you ask the same question multiple times? Please add your code and ask a specific question.

Comment: the question changes every time, just the layout is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know what your line contains - it's in `!line!`
You know what you want to find - it's in `!addafter!`

So - to find whether `!addafter!` is in `!line!` all you need to do is

```
echo !line!|findstr "!addafter!" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo not found) else (echo found)
```

So read the documentation shown by

```
findstr /?
```

and work out what you need to find "beginining" or "ending" with ... , whether or not you need case-insensitivity and whether you need to use you search-for-me-string as a literal or a "regular expression" (noting that by default REGULAR EXPRESSION is assumed) and whether or not you want to **C**ombine "a string with spaces" or search for "any word in a set" without **C**ombining them together as a single string.